# Can't install python module "pycrypto" on Debian lenny

Tags: python, debian, python-2.6, pycrypto, lenny

I tried to install pycrypto module by downloading the source code and executing the following command `python setup.py install`, then an error came

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.5 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.5/src/MD2.o
src/MD2.c:31:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
src/MD2.c:118: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
In file included from src/MD2.c:134:
src/hash_template.c:42: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'PyObject_HEAD'
src/hash_template.c:46: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'PyTypeObject'
src/hash_template.c: In function 'newALGobject':
src/hash_template.c:55: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyObject_New'
src/hash_template.c:55: error: expected expression before 'ALGobject'
src/hash_template.c:55: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
src/hash_template.c: At top level:
src/hash_template.c:62: error: expected ')' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:77: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:96: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:108: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:143: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:160: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ALG_methods'
src/hash_template.c:169: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:178: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'ALGtype'
src/hash_template.c:203: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
src/hash_template.c:237: error: array type has incomplete element type
src/hash_template.c:238: error: 'PyCFunction' undeclared here (not in a function)
src/hash_template.c:238: error: expected '}' before 'ALG_new'
src/hash_template.c: In function 'initMD2':
src/hash_template.c:254: error: 'PyObject' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/hash_template.c:254: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/hash_template.c:254: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/hash_template.c:254: error: 'm' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/hash_template.c:256: error: 'ALGtype' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/hash_template.c:256: error: 'PyType_Type' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/hash_template.c:257: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Py_InitModule'
src/hash_template.c:260: error: 'o' undeclared (first use in this function)
src/hash_template.c:260: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyInt_FromLong'
src/hash_template.c:260: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyDict_SetItemString'
src/hash_template.c:260: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyModule_GetDict'
src/hash_template.c:260: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Py_DECREF'
src/hash_template.c:263: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PyErr_Occurred'
src/hash_template.c:264: warning: implicit declaration of function 'Py_FatalError'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Which means that he didn't find the Python.h. I searched online for this error and it seems that by installing the python header file the problem will be solved, but my Debian lenny came with anther error.

```
apt-get install python2.6-dev
```

and error :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package python2.6-dev
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't install it from source.  Install the Debian package instead:

```
aptitude install python-crypto
```

And to install the python dev files (which you won't need anyway if you follow my above advice):

```
aptitude install python-dev
```

Comment: :Thanks a lot for your post, but it gives me the following 
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information
Initializing package states... Done
Reading task descriptions... Done
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 126 not upgraded.`