# ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, easy-install, pycrypto

When I try to run app.py (Python 3.3, PyCrypto 2.6) my virtualenv keeps returning the error listed above. My import statement is just `from Crypto.Cipher import AES`. I looked for duplicates and you might say that there are some, but I tried the solutions (although most are not even solutions) and nothing worked.

You can see what the files are like for PyCrypto below:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're in a virtualenv. Is your virtualenv activated properly?

Comment: @ChristianTernus It is activated properly.

Comment: I had the same issue. This will sound a bit lame but to resolve it just I stopped using OSX, I installed VirtualBox and a linux distro and it all worked :)

Comment: Wait what? `ImportError` is shown in `python 2` while in `python 3` it is `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: @BlackThunder, `python3 -c 'import foo'` yields `ImportError: No module named 'foo'`. Did I miss something?

Comment: @r2evans when importing the modules in code, if the module is not installed then the python 3 yields `ModuleNotFoundError` whereas python 2 yields`ImportError`. OP said that he used python 3 but the error is of python 2

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and don't disagree that there is `ModuleNotFoundError`, but every combination of command-line-arg/console/script-file and py2/py3 I've tried comes up with just `ImportError`. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong. (I'm not detracting from your comment, just trying to learn "why". Thanks.) Not critical, I do not want to try to hijack this question.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had the same problem (though on Linux). The solution was quite simple - add:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

to my `app.yaml` file. Since this worked correctly in the past, I assume this is a new requirement.

Comment: Just to add to this a little more, in my case this wasn't working as I had multiple versions of Python interpreters on my machine and I was installing the libraries in different versions. What I did was moved into the virtual environment and it worked as smooth as silk.

Comment: @neaGaze How did you "move into the virtual environment" to get it to work "smooth as silk"?

Comment: @Praxiteles Well it's been a while since I did that project but I think I used the Python virtual env setting. In Python you can either use a standalone version or the virtual environment. You can check out this link if you need more information http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv

Comment: This answer does not explain everything, where are you getting `app.yaml` file?

Comment: You shouldn't use `pycrypto` no more! Check my answer for a better solution!

Answer (score 230):

I had the same problem on my Mac when installing with `pip`. I then removed `pycrypto` and installed it again with `easy_install`, like this:

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
easy_install pycrypto
```

also as Luke commented: If you have trouble running these commands, be sure to run them as admin (sudo)

[As winklerr notes in their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/11107541), pycrypto is no longer safe. Use pycryptodome instead, it is a drop-in replacement

Comment: It's odd, but this fixed the issue on OS X Mavericks for me. I needed sudo for system wide libs.

Comment: thanks elad, i'm using 10.9.3 and i got same error. thanks a million

Comment: Also, if you have trouble running these commands, be sure to run them as admin (sudo)

Comment: I had installed it with pip, which didn't work, then easy_install, which also didn't work. (This is on Windows.) Simply uninstalling it with pip as you suggested somehow made it work. I would have never thought to do that in a million years. Thank you.

Comment: This still saves the day on El Capitan.

Comment: Can anyone explain why this works? (on OSX 10.11.4 with python from homebrew)

Comment: If you have installed Python through MacPort or other make sure you're using the correct easy_install and installing into the correct site-packages directory.

Comment: Save the day for Sierra

Comment: Don't forget `sudo` if it doesn't work. It won't even warn you that it doesn't have permissions and will appear to have installed something.

Comment: 2018, ubuntu based docker (on mac) image  (`FROM python:3.6.4`) and this still worked. Wow.

Comment: As winklerr correctly notes below, `pycrypto` is **no longer safe**. Use `pycryptodome` instead, it is a drop-in replacement.

Comment: This worked for me too. Mine is on Mac OS Catalina.

Comment: " Use pycryptodome instead, it is a drop-in replacement"  >> that worked for me

Answer (score 171):

## WARNING: Don't use `crypto` or `pycrypto` anymore!

As you can read on [this page](https://blog.sqreen.com/stop-using-pycrypto-use-pycryptodome/), the usage of `pycrypto` is **not** safe anymore:

> Pycrypto is vulnerable to a heap-based buffer overflow in the ALGnew function in block_templace.c. It allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code in the python application. It was assigned the [CVE-2013-7459](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2013-7459) number.
>
> Pycrypto didn’t release any fix to that vulnerability and no commit was made to the project since Jun 20, 2014.

#### Update 2021-01-18

The CVE is fixed now (thanks @SumitBadsara for pointing it out!). You can find the current status of the open security tickets for each package at the Debian security tracker:

- [`python-crypto`](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/python-crypto)
- [`pycryptodome`](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/pycryptodome)

## Use Python3's `pycryptodome` instead!

Make sure to uninstall all versions of `crypto` and `pycrypto` first, then install `pycryptodome`:

```
pip3 uninstall crypto 
pip3 uninstall pycrypto 
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

All of these three packages get installed to the same folder, named `Crypto`. Installing different packages under the same folder name can be a common source for errors!

For more information, see [pycryptodome.org](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/introduction.html).

### Best practice: virtual environments

In order to avoid problems with pip packages in different versions or packages that install under the same folder (i.e. `pycrypto` and `pycryptodome`) you can make use of a so called *virtual environment*. There, the installed pip packages can be managed for every single project individually.

To install a virtual environment and setup everything, use the following commands:

```
# install python3 and pip3
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install python3
sudo apt install python3-pip

# install virtualenv
pip3 install virtualenv

# install and create a virtual environment in your target folder
mkdir target_folder
cd target_folder
python3 -m virtualenv .

# now activate your venv and install pycryptodome
source bin/activate
pip3 install pycryptodome

# check if everything worked: 
# start the interactive python console and import the Crypto module
# when there is no import error then it worked
python
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> exit()

# don't forget to deactivate your venv again
deactivate
```

For more information, see [docs.python-guide.org](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/#lower-level-virtualenv).

Comment: If you currently have installations of crypto or pycrypto, you must uninstall them first.

Comment: It is fixed now 
https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2013-7459

Comment: The only answer worked for me - `pip install pycryptodome`

Comment: `pip install pycryptodome` worked!!! ( macOS) and the virtual environment is good too. a perfect cubicle for individual project. Awesome and thanks!!

Comment: I still get the Crypto module not found using this library as well

Comment: this worked thanks @winklerrr
pip3 uninstall crypto 
pip3 uninstall pycrypto 
pip3 install pycryptodome

Answer (score 129):

I ran into this on Mac as well, and it seems to be related to having an unfortunately similarly named "crypto" module (not sure what that is for) installed alongside of pycrypto via pip.

The fix seems to be removing both crypto and pycrypto with pip:

```
sudo pip uninstall crypto
sudo pip uninstall pycrypto
```

and reinstalling pycrypto:

```
sudo pip install pycrypto
```

Now it works as expected when I do something like:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

Comment: Same for me in Windows+Vagrant with Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and Python3

Comment: This works except that in a virtualenv don't use sudo

Answer (score 48):

**I found the solution.** Issue is probably in case sensitivity (on Windows).

**Just change the name of the folder:**

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\crypto
```

To this:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Crypto
```

**This is how folder was named after installation of pycrypto:**
[image]

**I've changed it to:**
[image]

**And now the following code works fine:**
[image]

Comment: This works, but there are too many of packages inside all need to be renamed.

Comment: @user1288329 Why would that be the case? Other packages are imported lowercase. Only renaming as Crypto worked for me.

Comment: This problem probably occurs because `crypto` was installed before, which created the directory lowercase. And case insensitive Windows put all things in the same directory afterwards.

Comment: I have run into this problem so many times and have never solved it. You, my good sir, are both a gentleman and a scholar. <hat tip>

Comment: the uppercase crypto will change to lowercase automatically sometimes, it it possible to fixed is forever?

Answer (score 42):

On the mac... if you run into this.. try to see if you can import crypto instead?

If so.. the package name is the issue `C` vs `c`.  To get around this.. just add these lines to the top of your script.

```
import crypto
import sys
sys.modules['Crypto'] = crypto
```

You know should be able to import paramiko successfully.

Comment: That's not correct, read a bit here: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/faq.html#why-do-i-get-the-error-no-module-named-crypto-on-windows

Comment: this is not work for me. I am using macOS 13.4

Answer (score 29):

Uninstalling `crypto` and `pycrypto` works on me. Then install only `pycrypto`:

```
pip uninstall crypto 
pip uninstall pycrypto 
pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: Here is the explanation to this solution from the docs: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/faq.html#why-do-i-get-the-error-no-module-named-crypto-on-windows

Comment: This worked for me, except with `pycryptodome` and `pycryptodomex`

Answer (score 26):

type command:

```
sudo pip install pycrypto
```

Comment: I found this while searching for a Linux solution (Debian). The following worked for me: [Can't install python module “pycrypto” on Debian lenny](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7913198/413180)

Answer (score 17):

If you are in a Mac OS, rename the lib folder:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/crypto
```

To this:

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto
```

Comment: This one worked for me as opposed to other solutions. I am on MacOs

Comment: Buried here is the solution that worked for me (on Windows 10)

Comment: this works for me on mac M1

Comment: This work for me on macOS 13.4 with M1 pro chip. why did this solve the issue?

Answer (score 11):

Run the following codes in your terminal screen

```
pip uninstall crypto
pip uninstall pycryptodome
pip install pycryptodome
```

Comment: is this library issue with different versions of python? Seemed to work fine for python 2

Comment: Problem with possible python versions. Please use one of the current python versions

Answer (score 8):

If you are using RedHat or a RedHat-based distro like Fedora or CentOS, you can install it with the following command:

```
sudo yum install pycrypto
```

In my case, I was not able to install it using `pip`.

Comment: This package name referenced seems to no longer exist on yum? "pycrypto"

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same problem `'ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher'`, since using GoogleAppEngineLauncher (version > 1.8.X) with GAE Boilerplate on OSX 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion). In Google App Engine SDK with python 2.7 runtime, pyCrypto 2.6 is the suggested version. 
The solution that worked for me was...

1) Download pycrypto2.6 source extract it somewhere(`~/Downloads/pycrypto26`)

e.g., git clone https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto.git

2) `cd` (`cd ~/Downloads/pycrypto26`)  then

3) Execute the following terminal command inside the previous folder in order to install pyCrypto 2.6 manually in GAE folder.

```
sudo python setup.py install --install-lib /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine
```

Comment: the OP's question has to do with Windows and not OSX

Comment: It might be useful to note that installing to the project root will also work (regardless of platform)

Comment: It's great answer for yosemite user!

Comment: @Lazaros Dinakis : This is the solution that worked.. of all the solutions mentioned in this page. Thanks

Comment: this answer solved it for me on mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.5. Only thing is the installation failed with errors for me. so i manually copied the Crypto lib from my python lib into the google_appengine lib. and now it works.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using this module with Python3 and having trouble with import.
try this.

```
pip uninstall crypto
pip uninstall pycryptodome
pip install pycryptodome
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 6):

Even after installing Crypto I was getting below error:

```
python my_script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\gitworkspace\cloudtools\py\my_script.py", line 19, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Then in this [post](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/issues/1137#issuecomment-272214227) I found the command that solved the issue.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Answer (score 5):

Well this might appear weird but after installing `pycrypto` or `pycryptodome` , we need to update the directory name `crypto` to `Crypto` in `lib/site-packages`

[Reference](https://github.com/openthread/openthread/issues/1137#issuecomment-548474372)

Comment: it works on my Win10

Answer (score 4):

It could be a problem of loading python modules installed via pip. Refer to this answer [Can't load Python modules installed via pip from site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory) and try something like

```
python -m pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me (Ubuntu 17.10)

Removing venv and creating it again with python v3.6

```
pip3 install PyJWT
sudo apt-get install build-essential libgmp3-dev python3-dev
pip3 install cryptography
pip3 install pycryptodome
pip3 install pycryptodomex
```

Pycrypto is deprecated, had problems with it, used Pycryptodome

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me

```
pip install pycryptodome==3.4.3
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem by change the first letter case to upper.
Make sure ''from Crypto.Cipher import AES'' not ''from crypto.Cipher import AES''.

Answer (score 3):

Try with **pip3**:

```
sudo pip3 install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 3):

**Step-1:** You are suggested to `uninstall` those libraries if it is installed on your machine

```
pip uninstall pycrypto
pip uninstall crypto
```

**Step-2:** Now, install the `pycryptodome` instead of `pycrypto` or `crypto`.
Hope, it will solve your problem.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

**Step-3:** As you need, you can import the relevant libraries.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

For CentOS 7.4 I first installed pip and then pycrypto using pip:

```
> sudo yum -y install python-pip 
> sudo python -m pip install pycrypto
```

Answer (score 2):

To date, I'm having same issue when importing `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` even when I've installed/reinstalled pycrypto a few times. End up it's because pip defaulted to python3.

```
~ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

installing pycrypto with pip2 should solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

One more reminder if you still encounter this issue after uninstall **crypto** and **pycrypto** like this

```
pip3 uninstall crypto
pip3 uninstall pycrypto
```

Just check if there is a directory named **crypto**(lower case) in your site-packages under
**/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages**, make sure the python version your used and the right site-packages path, then remove the **crypto** directory, the try to install again.

Answer (score 2):

this works for me:

```
pip install pycryptodomex
```

then

```
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows 7:**

I got through this error "Module error Crypo.Cipher import AES"

To install Pycrypto in Windows,

Try this in Command Prompt,

Set path=C:\Python27\Scripts  (i.e path where easy_install is located)

Then execute the following,

easy_install pycrypto

**For Ubuntu:**

Try this,

Download Pycrypto from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto"

Then change your current path to downloaded path using your terminal:

Eg: root@xyz-virtual-machine:~/pycrypto-2.6.1#

Then execute the following using the terminal:

python setup.py install

It's worked for me. Hope works for all..

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be fixed by installing the C++ compiler (python27 or python26). Download it from Microsoft https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266 and re-run the command : `pip install pycrypto` to run the gui web access when you kill the process of `easy_install.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add this to your `requirements.txt` file:

```
pycryptodome==3.6.1
```

Then install all dependencies using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This should eliminate the error report. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Python 3.7. The issue remains after I try to install `crypto`.

And `pycrypto` just fails in my case. So in the end my build passed by using the following package:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete your existing folder of `pycrypto/pycryptodome-3.11.0` located at:

```
..\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
```

Then run:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Answer (score 0):

I had simular problem and fixed it with the next command

```sh
sudo pip3 install py
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem in `django`. I was getting error while importing:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

Then I installed `pycryptodome` with:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Finally, I changed the code to :

```
from crypto.Cipher import AES
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this going to help anyone but I had the exact same issue trying to run: `samrdump` on Kali Linux.

after a lot of work (I checked similar issues on the repo [here](https://github.com/IdentityPython/pysaml2/issues/389)).
I discovered that  typing python3 instead of python (as python uses python2) solved the issue:

```
sudo python3 samrdump.py
sudo python3 smbclient.py
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution seems to be strange but I used to run my file like this,

```
encrypt.py
```

Than I run it like that and it worked

```
python encrypt.py
```