# How to use ssh with python on windows without paramiko?

Tags: python, linux, windows, ssh

On machine `A` I want to have a small python script to execute a command on machine `B`. Machine `A` is Windows with `freesshd` running on it, and machine `B` can be either Windows or Linux. I only have a username and a password to log in to machine `B`, no other way of authentication.

How can I create a python script to run a command on machine `B`? `ssh` would be fine, but where to find that command on Windows? And it has to be done without `paramiko`, since this module does not wok for unknown reasons.

Comment: Found similar question that actually installs paramico on windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514571/difficult-to-install-python-ssh-library-on-windows-ssh-has-been-replaced-with

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this on Windows but to handle input and output of a command pexpect is a good candidate. It also has a ssh part http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pxssh.html.

Did some more digging. There is a windows port of pexpect: https://gist.github.com/anthonyeden/8488763

Use that along with putty on the command line in windows.

Example of Putty on command line: http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get `paramiko` working, just do it manually with `Popen`: http://python-for-system-administrators.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ssh.html

Comment: @JohnPrawyn You'd need a cygwin-esque environment if you want to invoke `ssh` from the commandline or with `popen`. Otherwise you need a library like `paramiko` or `pyssh`.