# Can't load Python modules installed via pip from site-packages directory

Tags: python, macos, bash, module, evernote

I am trying to install and use the Evernote module (https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python) . I ran `pip install evernote` and it says that the installation worked.

I can confirm that the evernote module exists in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. However, when I try to run `python -c "import evernote"` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named evernote
```

This is the contents of my `.bash-profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for Python 3.3
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
```

I am having this same problem with other modules installed with `pip`. Help?

EDIT: I am a super newbie and have not edited that `.bash-profile` file.

EDIT: `python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'` Outputs the following:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools-1.3.2-py2.7.egg
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

**EDIT:** I seemed to have made progress towards a solution by adding `export PYTHONPATH=“/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages”` to my `.bash_profile` file. However, now when I run `python -c 'from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient'` it tries to import oauth2, which fails with the same error. The ouath2 module is present in the module directory.

Comment: I can confirm that I am using Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Try this line to check if Evernote SDK is installed `python -c 'from evernote.api.client import EvernoteClient'`

Comment: `python --version` gives my 2.7.5. I am not sure how that comment got added to the `.bash-profile`. I have Python 3 installed, but I have to use `python3` in order to use it.

Comment: That line is what I was using, and it does not work. I get `ImportError: No module named evernote.api.client`

Comment: What does `type python` output? what about `python -c 'import sys; print "\n".join(sys.path)'`?

Comment: `type python` gives me: `python is /usr/bin/python`

I updated my post with the output of that second command.

Comment: This worked for me: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-module-from-different-directory/

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`/usr/bin/python` is the executable for the python that comes with OS X. `/usr/local/lib` is a location for user-installed programs only, possibly from Python.org or Homebrew. So you're mixing different Python installs, and changing the python path is only a partial workaround for different packages being installed for different installations.

In order to make sure you use the `pip` associated with a particular python, you can run `python -m pip install <pkg>`, or go look at what the `pip` on your path is, or is symlinked to.

Comment: `python -m pip install <pkg>` seems to work beautifully.

Comment: What does `-m` do?

Comment: @acollection_ : -m is from library Module

Comment: python -m pip install <pkg> is the best workaround. Alternately, you can also do this: 
-> import sys
-> sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")

Adding these two lines to your python script or typing them in the interpreter works the same way.

Comment: I get `/usr/bin/python: No module named pip` when I try to use this command.

Answer (score 63):

I figured it out! I added this line:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

to my `.bash_profile` and now I can import modules stored in that directory. Thanks for everyone who  answered.

Comment: I got the feeling that solved the whole python not working on mac EPIC. Thanx!

Comment: It's also common problem with python3. That solution also works with that

Comment: This didn't work for me when pointing to Python3 site package folder

Answer (score 6):

I faced similar problem,its related to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages had no read or write permission for group and other, and they were owned by root. This means that only the root user could access them.

Try this:

```
$ sudo chmod -R go+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

Answer (score 4):

None of this helped me with my similar problem. Instead, I had to fix the newly installed files **permissions** to be able to import. This is usually an obvious thing, but not so much when you use `sudo` when installing module/packages.

Comment: I also had to delete some `.pyc` files from one of my packages. I think they were created after I had made the package directory readable, but before I made the package subdirs readable. The error message I was receiving which led me to the `.pyc` file problem was: 

`File "requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>`
`from . import utils`
`ImportError: cannot import name utils`

In my case, I think it was `__init__.pyc` which was the problem, but I removed all `.pyc` files to be sure.

Lesson: Do `chmod -R a+rX site-package-module-dir` as described in @prarit-lamba's answer

Answer (score -6):

Simply just type in terminal:

```
sudo pip install pillow
```

and type `import` (whatever you like) or type `from` (whatever you like) `import` (whatever you like).