# importing numpy in python3

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

In the terminal I did `pip install numpy`. It seems as if I can access `numpy` in the terminal but not in the shell.

How can I import `numpy` into the shell? I keep getting `import error: no module named numpy`.

I am using Python 3.

Many thanks.

Comment: What operating system are you on?  Do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory).

Comment: I am using python 3.4 with pycharm on a mac. I did 'pip install numpy' in the terminal but that installs it for 2.7, not 3.4. That's why when I import bumpy in python3, it doesn't find anything.

Comment: Did you try `pip3 install numpy`?