# "ImportError: No module named selenium"

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip

```
Installed selenium using pip : pip install selenium<br>
pip version : pip 8.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)<br>

python version : Python 2.7.5
```

Wasn't getting this error earlier.

```
"ImportError: No module named selenium"
```

Upgraded pip a while ago and started getting this error. Couldn't find anything useful from earlier questions.

sys.path:
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Can anyone please help?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Do you know the directory where selenium was installed before?  Does that directory still exist?

Comment: where this error occur? your code before this import error.

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't remember the earlier directory...Currently it is in : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: Try this code: `import sys; print(sys.path)` Is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` in the output?

Comment: Well, that would explain it.  Can you show us what _is_ in the output?

Comment: @JohnGordon Output was too long to be written in comment. So have edited the question to include the output. Please check the question.

Comment: Is there supposed to be any connection between `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: Found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory

Comment: Worked with this command : python -m pip install <pkg>

Comment: Thank You, Officer Gordon :)

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you have multiple python interpreters in your machine.

check what is your default interpreter by  python in your terminal and press ENTER.

if it is same as the version mentioned y PIP while installing, you should not have any problems.

or else,

change your default interpreter by keeping alias in your bash file,

append below line as last line as per your interpreter version

```
alias python='/usr/bin/python2.7.6'
```