# Can't install psycopg2 successfully

Tags: postgresql

```
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

This is the error message I get when I run

```
pip install psycopg2
```

in my terminal on Mac. But when I try to import it in python (simply using import psycopg2) in either version 2.7 or 3.6 of python I get an error message:

```
No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `python -c "import site; site.getsitepackages()"` print? What does `which python` print?

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: Looks OK. It's possible that the permissions on the install are preventing you from accessing the module. That and some other possibilities are mentioned in answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory)