# py2cairo, cairo getting installed through homebrew but not getting imported - MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Tags: python-3.5, igraph, cairo, pycairo

after installing `py2cairo`, `cairo` and `igraph` through homebrew, I ran across an issue where the cairo library is not getting imported.

I tried to run the following code in python3 shell

```
>>> from igraph import *
>>> g = Graph.Famous("petersen")
>>> plot(g)
```

And it gave me the error: TypeError: plotting not available

When I ran `import cairo` in the shell, it gave me:

```
>>> import cairo
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'cairo'
```

For debugging, please refer to the commands I used to install cairo, py2cairo and igraph

```
brew install cairo, py2cairo
brew install homebrew/science/igraph
```

And they are available in the following path:
    /usr/local/Cellar/

When I look at my python path, it is:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py'>
```

None of `py2cairo` and `cairo` installations are available at the following path `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/`, however `igraph` is present at the path

Can anyone help me solving this issue?

===========================================================================
UPDATE:

I tried solving the issue by (refer: [Can't load Python modules installed via pip from site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory)) running the following commands from the python shell and this time I can import cairo inside python shell.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar")
>>> import cairo
```

However, it fails on the `plot(g)` line with the following error.

```
>>> plot(g)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 446, in plot
result = Plot(target, bbox, background=kwds.get("background", "white"))
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-    packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
    self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
AttributeError: module 'cairo' has no attribute 'Surface'
```

ANY help would be appreciated

Comment: So this is unsolved?

Comment: Any solutions you found?