# How do I install a package that enable Jupyter load it?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I already have `imageio` installed:

```
$ pip install imageio
Requirement already satisfied: imageio in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from imageio)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from imageio)
```

Now I load a `.ipynb` file with Jupyter:

```
$ jupyter notebook 1_notmnist.ipynb
```

got error:

```
ImportError: No module named imageio
```

I thought it has something to do with [Can't load Python modules installed via pip from site-packages directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276329/cant-load-python-modules-installed-via-pip-from-site-packages-directory), and follow exactly as the answer suggest to reinstall `imageio`:

`$ python -m pip install imageio`

and still no help.

How do I install `imageio` that enable Jupyter load it?

update:

Terminal: `$ which python`

> /usr/bin/python

Jupyter:

```
$ import sys
print sys.executable
```

> /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7

Comment: In jupyter, what’s the path when sys.executable is run?

Comment: Jupyter doesn't necessarily run the same Python. For example, are you using a Python3 kernel?

Comment: datawrestler, cricket_007 
I guess that's the problem. The ultimate solution would be uninstall the extra Python and reset the path?

Answer (score 6):

You can install module by jupter notebook, just paste:

```
!pip install imageio
```

In your notebook, then it will be work.

Could be that you install it on python2 and it is not available on jupyter, or you are using virtual env.

---

Update:
If you will add

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

to your notebook then your notebook will be see installed packages (you should import it without an error).

Answer (score 1):

When I got a similar error with Jupyter Notebook and Mac OS, I ran the following in Terminal:

`sudo conda install imageio`

Answer (score 0):

`python2.7` might already be on the PATH, but if not you can do

```
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -m pip install imageio
```

Or you can install a Jupyter kernel for your system's Python

Comment: Doesn't work how? You need to run that from the terminal, not Jupyter, by the way.