# ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python, importerror, pycrypto

I am working with pycrypto. It works fine on my local windows machine, but when I move it to my python box I get an error with importing the module:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4 
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

The output of `python3.3 -c "from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4"`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

output of pip3 list has a reference includes pycrypto (2.6.1)

I know it works with Python 2.7.6, but I wrote the script in 3.3 so it depends on some things from 3.3

Comment: what is your python box? You have actually installed all the packages for python3 on your box also?

Comment: the box is running Ubuntu 14.04 x64. I added the package with pip3 on both my local machine and the box.

Comment: when you try `pip3 install pycrypto ` what do you see in the output, in specific the directory listed

Comment: OK, I think I figured it out, pip installed the pycryto module to the python3.4 directory. I copied the folders over to 3.3 and it is working now. Thank you for the help =)

Comment: No worries, I would use python3.4 myself unless you have a good reason not to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that your "python box" is a remote computer.

First, make sure pycrypto is up to date (`pip3 install --upgrade pycrypto`). The older versions may not be compatible with python 3.3

If that doesn't work, try looking in site-packages (the directory) to make sure the functions actually exist.

If none of that works, it might be easier (just a suggestion) to use `from future import` the things you need. That way it is python 2&3 compatible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got it sorted out by copying the folder in site-packages from my 3.4 location to the 3.3 one.

Comment: It couldn't work with python 3.6.1 I have no idea why?

Comment: @RyanChou you probably want to use cryptography https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/ instead, I think PyCrypto is defunct (hasn't seen work since 2014).

Comment: @IronManMark20 OK, I got it.

Answer (score 16):

As I already wrote in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/3459910):

## WARNING: Don't use `pycrypto` anymore!

Use `pycryptodome` instead, via `pip3 install pycryptodome`.

But make sure that you don't have `pycrypto` installed, because both packages install under the same folder `Crypto`.

Comment: What is the reasoning for abandoning the use of `pycrypto`?

Comment: The original reason for this post (an unsolved CVE) has been solved, so it is now safe to use pycrypto again.

Answer (score 0):

Use pycryptodome, either install using pip or in case using IDE like pycharm install as a package via Preferences.

In case still gives error, use pycryptodomex (different from pycryptodome).

You will not see any error in importing from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

[image: 1]