# File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycrypto

Unable to install `pycrypto`

```
Python 3.7.8 (tags/v3.7.8:4b47a5b6ba, Jun 28 2020, 07:55:33) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

How to install `pycrypto`?

Comment: how to resolve this guys?
and I'm having an error installing pycrypto module, what to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355385/importerror-no-module-named-crypto)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is very simple. it means you don't have a module that named crypto and the solution is

try open CMD "in Linux terminal" and write - `pip uninstall pycrypto` - and reinstall it with under command

```
pip install pycrypto
```

or

```
pip install crypto
```

and next try for import Crypto

Comment: i've done this but still i got this error.