# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycryptodome

I have installed pycryptodomex module on python 3.6.5 but when i try to execute the below call, i get the error mentioned in the headline

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
```

I want to encrypt a file using AES. How to proceed now ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
>> pip install pycryptodome

from Crypto.Cipher import AES  #Works
```

or

```
>> pip install pycryptodomex
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
```

For python3 the package name is now *pycryptodome* or *pycryptodomex*

If you need compatibility with your project with *Python2* use *pycryptodome* or else use *pycryptodomex* which is a library independent of the old PyCrypto.

Comment: It Worked ! Probably i was trying to install modules which are probably no more managed or not compatible.

Comment: Using module name `pycryptodomex` worked for me! thanks.

Comment: Cryptodome and pycryptodomex work for Python 3.9

Answer (score 13):

hello i had the same problem:
_an almost drop-in replacement for the old PyCrypto library. You install it with:

$ pip install pycryptodome ((3.8.2)) or the latest version
go to this directory :
2) [C:\Users\s****\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\crypto]

here try to change the file name crypto to Crypto with upper case C because they import it as Crypto in every package.
it works for me, good luck :)

Comment: The given directory matched 100%, thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 6):

[According to the PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodomex/), `pycryptodomex` is available under the name `Cryptodome` instead of `Crypto`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install the Cryptography package.
Visit [here](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/) for more details.

Or you can try pip install at the terminal:

```
pip3 install pycrypto
```

Comment: That's for Python2, he explicitly mentioned Python3.

Comment: @NoorAliJafri it works for both, provided what version of python he has installed. If he has installed both all he has to do is use pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: I checked with both the versions in both the cases it's installing pycrypto but with pip3 it works to import crypto.cipher. Just mention that tiny detail.

Comment: For those who are running Python 3.8.x and are attempting to install the package that makes `Crypto.Cipher.AES` available: `pip3 install pycrypto` is exactly what I needed. No idea what cryptodome is and why you'd need it over pycrypto...

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed cryptodome, you can try to create a symbolic link

`ln -s Cryptodome Crypto`

Comment: I would not recommend this solution, it will work locally on his machine but will blow upon deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 3.6.9.I had to do:

python3.6 -m pip install pycryptodome