# error in Crypto.Cipher.IDEA module in python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

> Hello there,

```
i am writing a code for auto discovery of IP within the network and then 
data transfer using the socket programming in python. I have read the RSA 
and want to implement in the code. i go through to the link where i got 
the code implementation and the whole code for server and client.
Here is the link where the code is:

<https://riptutorial.com/python/example/27170/client-side-implementation>
<https://riptutorial.com/python/example/27169/server-side-implementation>

There are two links and the setup for PyCrypto is.

*PyCrypto (Download Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto )

*PyCryptoPlus (Download Link: https://github.com/doegox/python-cryptoplus )
```

i tried it on raspberry pi and install all the essential modules which i wrote above, and run it using the command line as follows:
    python3 server.py 
   but it gives me some module related errors.

```
Crypto.Cipher.IDEA isn't available. You're probably using the Debian 
pycrypto version. Install the original pycrypto for IDEA.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "serverRsa.py", line 10, in <module>
from CryptoPlus.Cipher import IDEA
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/CryptoPlus/Cipher/IDEA.py", line 4, in <module>
import Crypto.Cipher.IDEA
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto.Cipher.IDEA'
```

i tried it using the pip install PyCrypto and using the same with pip3.
and then run the same code but same error occurred.

```
Actually problem statement is to auto discover of all the nearby ip's 
using the python programming , where i run the code on Raspberry Pi and 
make it as a hotspot and other Pi boards act as client. Now when the 
server found the client or discover them then it register them using some 
key or encryption method.
```

i just need or code that passes some message to client using RSA but it seems the code have error.
Anyone please fix this issue.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824628/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-crypto-error/51824838#51824838

Comment: i seen this , and install the same , but the same error occurs  As importerror: No module named IDEA

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use IDEA, an algorithm that's been obsolete for over a decade? What does this have to do with RSA? What does this have to do with IP discovery? If you want to communicate securely over a network, use TLS instead of rolling your own broken cryptography.

Comment: hello gilles, i want to use security because i need to communicate only with the registered ip's within my pi boards if they are not registerd in my pi boards then they can't communicate with it.

Answer (score 0):

Crypto.Cipher doesn't have any attribute named: *IDEA*.

```
import Crypto.Cipher.IDEA #won't work -_-
```

Maybe what you are looking for is CryptoPlus:

```
import CryptoPlus.Cipher.IDEA
```

Comment: yes you are right but when i run the program it shows me this error. please see the link which i given above in which it is defined like from CryptoPlus.Cipher import IDEA

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an IDEA cipher in Python 2, and it's OK for you that it's slow (much slower than if it was implemented in C), there is one here: https://pastebin.com/hTn5K3Tx . Use it like this:

```
cb = IDEA('2bd6459f82c5b300952c49104881ff48'.decode('hex'))
plaintext, ciphertext = 'f129a6601ef62a47'.decode('hex'), 'ea024714ad5c4d84'.decode('hex')
assert cb.encrypt(plaintext) == ciphertext
assert cb.decrypt(ciphertext) == plaintext
```

Please note that the last patent on IDEA expired in 2012, and now IDEA is [free to use for the public](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Standard Crypto Ciphers installed with `pip install pycrypto` now is version 2.6.1 and because of license restrictions it doesn't include IDEA (Crypto.Cipher.IDEA)
If you want to install Crypto.Cipher.IDEA you must find `pycrypto-2.0.1` (freely available for download) which was last used to embedded this crypto cipher see pts comment above. Then follow the standard procedure to install the package pycrypto

```
python setup.py install
```

Problem appear if want to install IDEA for pyton3.