# pyrebase install on windows Python 3.7 fails

Tags: python-3.x, pyrebase

I just installed python 3.7 64 bits on windows 10 for all u
sers and modified the PATH
I updated the pip to 18.1
I installed pygame, with

`py -3 -m pip install pygame`

it works fine

I wanted to install pyrebase with

`py -3 -m pip install pyrebase`

Download fine then I have this msg and the pip log dir is erased, so I can't figure out what is hapenning

> Command ""C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\mine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rr8v7jh\pycryptodome\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\mine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-om6lqxmm\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\mine\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2rr8v7jh\pycryptodome\

but before it gives this error

> Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, pyrebase
>
> Found existing installation: pycryptodome 3.7.0
>
> Uninstalling pycryptodome-3.7.0:
>
> Successfully uninstalled pycryptodome-3.7.0
>
> Running setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error

this is when I tried to install pycryptodome, which installed well alone, but when trying to install pyrebase it uninstall the previous pycryptodome and try it own but fails.

Any advice? thanks

**Edit:**
I tried

> pip install --upgrade setuptools

as suggested in https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/179

but it didn't solve my issue

I am still having an error, on Windows10, python 3.7:

> Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, pyrebase   Running
>   setup.py install for pycryptodome ... error
>       Complete output from command "C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a9kop2nb\pycryptodome\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-dm88ctzw\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile:

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To install https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase

I needed to download the .zip file (or Git) than manually install it after modifying the `setup.py`  by specifying the latest `'pycryptodome==3.7.3'` 
then copy the pyrebase\ directory to my python install

```
c:\WPy-3710\python-3.7.1.amd64\Lib\site-packages\
```

but the previous comment of @silkindustry showed me a new lib/Wrapper: Pyrebase4 
https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4

that install easily with

```
pip3 install pyrebase4
```

Comment: Hi sir, I am having this exact same problem in my other computer, I could not install pyrebase but I was able to install it with pyrebase4 but it still says 'unable to import pyrebase' any idea of what might be going on? @Lotfi

Comment: I noticed I had to use `from pyrebase import pyrebase` but now I am getting error on storage: No value for argument 'filename' in method call. weird it worked on my main PC with pyrebase instead of pyrebase4

Comment: After his `zip download and put`, the 'genius' forgot to add that you have to install through manually by navigating to the new module directory and from there doing `python setup.py install` and then you finally check if the module was installed by `python -c "import pyrebase"`

Answer (score 5):

Just upgrade setuptools (Successfully installed setuptools-40.6.3) with your suggested command and install newer version of Pyrebase. (Pyrebase4).

Answer (score 2):

first install pycryptodome version 3.10.1

```
pip install pycryptodome==3.10.1
```

then install pyrebase4

```
pip install pyrebase4
```

It work for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it using the following steps.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

and then I ran

```
pip install pyrebase
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because `pip install pyrebase` just uninstalls pycryptodome and tries to install it again itself.

Comment: A new lib/Wrapper: Pyrebase4 https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4

that install easily with

pip3 install pyrebase4

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I was working with Anaconda which runs python 3.7 as its default python interpreter. So I created a virtual environment with Python 3.6 with
`conda create --name env_name python=3.6`
Then with `conda activate env_name` activate the environment and run `pip install pyrebase`
and it should be installed.

Answer (score 1):

As Lotfi said, go to the pyrebase repository, https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase and download the .zip file of git repository and then  edit as he said,then save the /pyrebase folder to site packeges folder, if you still found no module error(Crypto) then visit this link, [ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Step 1: Follow the [answer given by Nayan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65086350/12559930) and [answer by Lotfi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480973/12559930). But use `'pycryptodome==VERSION_OF_PYCRYPTODOME_YOU_HAVE_ALREADY_INSTALLED'`.
Ex. `'pycryptodome==3.10.1'`

Step 2: After that Go to the site-packages/Pyrebase folder with updated setup.py file.

Step 3: Install the Pyrebase library **from that folder**. For that use command

`python setup.py install`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't solve the issue although I tried the above solutions.

Finally I can install pyrebase like following.

1. Re-install Python at C:\Pyton. : To avoid searching error of C:\Users...
2. Install JWS manually. Specify file format by UTF8 at setup.py file.
3. Install pycryptodomex not pycryptodome.
4. When make Project check following "inherit global site-packages"

Comment: new lib/Wrapper: Pyrebase4 https://github.com/nhorvath/Pyrebase4

that install easily with

pip3 install pyrebase4

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same issue with Anaconda, then i solved it by opening the command prompt of Anaconda and type the following,

1. `pip install pycryptodome` and then i ran
2. `pip install pyrebase4`, these two commands help to clear the issue

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Pycharm you can install the pyrebase5 or any other modules directly from it without getting any error.

1. Go to Files
2. Open the settings(Ctrl+Alt+s if you're using Win10)
3. Go to the Project >> project interpreter

Now you can see all the packages installed in the root folder of python.
(Make sure your your project interpreter is selected to the python root folder :
C:\Users\ (Username)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

4. In project interpreter you can see the +(Install) sign in the right. Click on it
5. the available packages window id open
6. Now you can search any packages you want to install like pyrebase: you can see all the versions of the pyrebase.
7. select the package and install package.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When answering to an old question that already has an accepted answer ensure your answer adds something substantial new. Don't answer if not. (The question wasn't related to PyCharm).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with the 2 steps below. I hope this is going to solve yours as well.

1. uninstall **pyrebase**:

   ```
   pip uninstall pyrebase
   ```
2. Install **Pyrebase-t**:

   ```
   pip install Pyrebase-t
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was **deactivating the virtual environment and reactivating it** before trying

```
pip install pyrebase
```