# How to use the crypto library for python 3 in the windows command prompt? Simply importing gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, command-prompt

Anytime I try to import crypto it gives the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crypto'
```

I'm able to use it in a program written in pycharm but not in the command prompt. I am using it for AES encryption in a program I wrote. I know in python 2 the module used to be Crypto with a capital C but beyond that i'm not sure what changes were made for python 3 that require me to do something before I can import crypto.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pycrypto by using `pip install pycryptodome`

See the below links for more information.
https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/aes.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/4416405

Comment: Oh dang okay. So crypto is just totally out of commission? hopefully this doesn't mean I need to redo the program. That would definitely suck. Thanks though I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Hey man. So I followed those instructions but even after uninstalling everything then installing pycryptodome, im still getting a similar error. When I try to import Crypto.Cipher it doesnt seem to like it and says `no module named Crypto`