# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = b'Sixteen byte key'
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_EAX)

nonce = cipher.nonce
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
```

This is my code, I'm trying to import AES from Crypto.Cipher, but shows this error.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher) answer your question ?

Comment: pip install pycryptodome did for me

Comment: did you fixed this isssue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve your issue:

```
pip install pycryptodome
```

Comment: this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue on macOS 13.4 with M1 chip, found the site package and remame the package name from:

```
venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/crypto
```

to:

```
venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Crypto
```

make sure install the `pycryptodome` package.