# Error installing pycrypto (with pyPrivnote)

Tags: python, installation, pip

I've been trying to install pycrypto for the last couple hours now and its not really working, could someone please help?

The commands and steps I've tried
`pip install pycrypto`
`easy_install pycrypto`
Installing Build Tools

But i keep getting the following error: https://pastebin.com/GatwaM9n, can someone help? (I ran installation as admin too)

Comment: Btw, The error is inside of pyPrivnote when im running my bot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/7976758: `pip install pycryptodome`

Comment: @phd could you make that an answer question so I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Mostly copying from https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/7976758 by @winklerrr:

## WARNING: Don't use `crypto` or `pycrypto` anymore!

As you can read on [this page](https://blog.sqreen.com/stop-using-pycrypto-use-pycryptodome/), the usage of `pycrypto` is **not** safe anymore:

> Pycrypto is vulnerable to a heap-based buffer overflow in the ALGnew function in block_templace.c. It allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code in the python application. It was assigned the [CVE-2013-7459](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2013-7459) number.
>
> Pycrypto didn’t release any fix to that vulnerability and no commit was made to the project since Jun 20, 2014.

**Update 2021-01-18:** The CVE is fixed now (thanks @SumitBadsara for pointing it out!). You can find the current status of the open security tickets for each package at the Debian security tracker:

- [`python-crypto`](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/python-crypto)
- [`pycryptodome`](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/source-package/pycryptodome)

## Use Python3's `pycryptodome` instead!

Make sure to uninstall all versions of `crypto` and `pycrypto` first, then install `pycryptodome`:

```
pip3 uninstall crypto 
pip3 uninstall pycrypto 
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

(*phd* — skipping a part about virtual environments…)

All of these three packages get installed to the same folder, named `Crypto`. Installing different packages under the same folder name can be a common source for errors!

For more information, see [pycryptodome.org](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks ;) Really helped me out!