# Install Crypto using pip in windows

Tags: python, pycrypto

I tried with pycrypto, pycryptodome, and crypto seperately.. But it shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'`

```
python -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
pip install pycryptodome
pip install pycrypto
pip install crypto
```

Installed all the above library..

```
(.venv) C:\Users\Gokul\Desktop\New Meter>python send_string.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gokul\Desktop\New Meter\send_string.py", line 7, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Comment: The virtualenv might not be updating `pip3` symlink. Try `python -m pip install pycryptodome` (and don't use the others https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/2308683)

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer, Installing pycryptodome is working fine..  Please check the pip and pip3 is typo error.. kindly check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply **deleted** my existing folder of pycrpto/pycryptodome-3.11.0 located at ..\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages (if any..), then tried

`pip install pycryptodome`