# How to fix Running setup.py install for PyCrypto did not run successfully error

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install python library, but when I trying to install library using pip I it's throw error like.....

```
C:\Users\Nayan>pip install PyCrypto
Collecting PyCrypto
Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyCrypto, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyCrypto
Running setup.py install for PyCrypto ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for PyCrypto did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [153 lines of output]
```

Comment: Seems like PyCrypto has not been updated from Python 3.3. Which Python version are you using?

Comment: python version 3.10.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20PyCrypto

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077358/7976758