# No module named 'rng_base'

Tags: python, django, pycrypto

It's error when I run python manage.py runserver. I google but no answer can fix my error please help.

```
  File "/Users/ahkomu/Documents/myproject/account/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from utils.encryption import AESCipher
  File "/Users/ahkomu/Documents/myproject/utils/encryption.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/Users/ahkomu/Documents/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import OSRNG
  File "/Users/ahkomu/Documents/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.OSRNG.posix import new
  File "/Users/ahkomu/Documents/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Crypto/Random/OSRNG/posix.py", line 32, in <module>
    from rng_base import BaseRNG
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rng_base'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher) (You're using pycrypto which isn't supported anymore, use pycryptodome instead as per answers on the linked question)

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know which version of Crypto/pycrypto you're using but it looks like pycrypto is not well supported: [ImportError: No module named Crypto.Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19623267/importerror-no-module-named-crypto-cipher/58077358#58077358)

It is possible that your version of Crypto is not compatible with the version of Python 3.9 you have installed since 3.9 was release in 2020.

Try creating your venv with a version of python that existed at the time your version of Crypto was released.

This also discusses an issue with posix: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5074

Answer (score 0):

Go to the source code of `pycrypto` in your local machine and, in file

```
Random/OSRNG/posix.py
```

change the line

```
from rng_base import BaseRNG
```

by

```
from Crypto.OSRNG.rng_base import BaseRNG
```